Unity App is not responding to clicks on devices with android 14
we have been publishing our app since 2021, and everything works fine, but in our latest version in 6 of april, we published our unity game with target api level 34, and after publishing the app is not responding to any click on the first screen on some devices with android 14, or people who updated their phone to android 14 in these two weeks, we have no crash report, no exception, and we don't know what to do, we did a very big campaign with google add and spend a huge amount of money on this but barely anyone can use the app.
The app stops on the first screen and you can't do anything with it.
App name on google play : Meet 2 play
Unity version 2022.3.21
minimum API Level 29
Target API Level 34
Some additional information



Reminder that just posting screenshots doesn't help anyone understand your issue. What debugging steps have you done. What libraries are you using and what if anything was found in your logs.

hi, i have attached the device to android logcat and no error related to anything like that just some warnings, for libraries and sdks i'm using onesignal, agora engine and google play service.
